# Logic app is triggered twice on blob upload

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I am running a logic app which is triggered on a storage event (blob created) but everytime i upload a blob using winscp, the logic app is triggered twice. any reason ?

[image: Event Subscription]

Logic app flow

[image]

Trigger size

[image]

Comment: please share your flow diagram

Comment: I have added the storage event and logic app flow images

Answer (score 1):

Some systems will generate an empty blob reference and then overwrite it. This initial 0 byte blob will fire the Created event. The overwriting blob containing the data will then also fire the Created event. We've seen this occasionally with long running processes like SSIS.

We solved it by adding a check in the Logic App to test the size:

[image]

If the size is 0, we do nothing.

Comment: But in the trigger history when i see both the triggers they are of same size, none is of 0 byte...added the screenshot

Comment: Isn't that the size of the trigger, not the size of the actual blob?